# Sharing 'this' between files

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I'm working on creating an object that will have many methods, and trying to avoid my files being incredibly long.  The problem is some of methods refer to other information in the object. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

index.js

```
var User = function(first, last){
  this.firstname = first;
  this.lastname = last;
};

User.prototype.name = require('./methods/name.js')
```

methods/name.js

```
module.exports = {
  full: function(){
      return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
  },
  formal: function(){
      return "Mr. " + this.lastname;
  }
};
```

It makes sense why `this` doesn't work in this situation, but is there a different solution to be able to reference the other file?  The only I can think of is using fs and `eval()` instead of require, but that seems like a hack to me, or the obvious of have a long file. Is there something better?

I'm planning on having about 35 objects on the prototype with each having an average of 4 methods on it.  Suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Your code would work if the module exported a function. You cannot nest objects on the prototype, `this` will always refer to the last object in the chain, not to the instance.

Comment: Instead of just `require`, you could list the methods explicitly, allowing you to `bind` them and assign them to individual fields. Like so: `var req = require('x.js'); User.prototype.name = {full: req.full.bind(this), formal: req.formal.bind(this)};` You could also use a loop on each object.

Comment: As an aside this feels like a bad design to me.

Comment: @Paul, In my experience, imported methods can be very useful.

Comment: Although many would not agree I think a more functional approach would be better. If you just have the functions and data be separate and just pass the data into the functions then you get the benefit of  not needing to know about the other code to add functionality that operates on that data. Here's a great book on it: https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/index.html

Comment: 35 * 4 methods related to a single object is either: not an object, but a namespace (lodash style), or, a terrible, terrible design (SOLID principles)

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan>  In my experience as well.  I was more thinking about the approach of stacking *that much* into one object (even if composed from multiple files).  As @Amit says, it doesn't feel very SOLID to me, and probably violates SRP as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with it being in separate files. You would get the same problem all in one file if you defined User like this:

```
var User = function(first, last){
  this.firstname = first;
  this.lastname = last;
};

User.prototype.name = {
  full: function(){
      return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
  },
  formal: function(){
      return "Mr. " + this.lastname;
  }
};
```

Since when you call `someuser.name.full()` the `this` will be bound to `someuser.name` not `someuser`.

If you don't need to namespace those functions and only did so because you were unsure how else to extend the prototype from another file, you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign( User.prototype, require('./methods/name.js') );
```

Then you'll be able to call `someuser.full()` or `someuser.formal()` and of course `this` will have the correct value.

Comment: Ah yes! This is the way to do it! Green check.

Comment: It _is_ more of a namespacing issue.  I'm building out a way to access all the endpoints of an API.  the namespaces are the different portions of the api, and the methods are the calls to the endpoints.  The authentication info for each call is what I'm trying to grab with `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can **bind** those functions like this:

```
User.prototype.name = require('./methods/name').bind(this)
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
>
> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Also—lose the `.js` in your require path.

Comment: Pretty much my comment, except the way I understand the question, the result of `require` is an object containing two functions.

Comment: Then all he has to do is drop another `.funcName` between the require() and the `.bind`. As in: `require('./methods/name').funcName.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0):

This should keep your code modular

// index.js

```
var userMethods = require('.methods/name.js');
var User = function(first, last){
  this.firstname = first;
  this.lastname =  last;
};

User.prototype.name = userMethods.full;
User.prototype.formalName = userMethods.formal;

var Abbey = new User('Abbey', 'Jack');

console.log(Abbey.firstname); // Abbey
console.log(Abbey.lastname); // Jack
console.log(Abbey.name()); // Abbey Jack
console.log(Abbey.formalName()); // Mr. Jack
```

// methods/name.js

```
module.exports = {
  full: function(){
      return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
  },
  formal: function(){
      return "Mr. " + this.lastname;
  }
};
```